# routerLinkActive not working for <li> and <a> Combination

Tags: angular, routerlinkactive

The links below Works for me:

```
<li routerLink="/profile/education" [routerLinkActive]="'active-link'">Education</li>

<li routerLink="/profile/education" [routerLinkActive]="'active-link'"><span>Education</span></li>

<a routerLink="/profile/education" [routerLinkActive]="'active-link'">Education</a>

<h1><a routerLink="/profile/basic" [routerLinkActive]="'active-link'">Education</a></h1>
```

But the link doesn't work for me:

```
<li><a routerLink="/profile/basic" [routerLinkActive]="'active-link'">Education</a></li>
```

I want to know what's the problem with li and a combination?

Comment: replace `routerLink` with `[routerLink]`

Comment: @BahadorRaghibizadeh Why should I do that. I hard-coded the link, not binding property. I get error doing this

Comment: @Md.Rafee what do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: Do you get any errors, and have you tried with something like <button> instead of <a> ?

Maybe your routes are not setup correctly?

Comment: Doesn't work?! It was a style "problem"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your CSS maybe it will be on li(tag) not for a(tag). You can put CSS active class on a(tag)

Comment: Yes, it was my problem in css. Thanks